# syslog-ng not receiving logs from Cisco Router

Tags: networking, syslog, cisco

Greetings of the day!

I have configured syslog-ng with a very simple configuration which is as follows-

I have made direct changes on - 
/etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf

And here is what I have added - 
source s_net { udp(ip(192.168.145.140) port(514)); };
destination path { file("/var/log/dev.log"); };
filter ipaddr { host( "192.168.122.205" ); };
log { source ( s_net ); filter( ipaddr ); destination ( path ); };

192.168.145.140 - Is the Ubuntu 16.04/syslog server
192.168.122.205 - Is the Cisco Router

There is reach ability-
Router1#ping 192.168.145.140

Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 192.168.145.140, timeout is 2 seconds:
!!!!!

distro@ubuntu:/home$ ping 192.168.122.205
PING 192.168.122.205 (192.168.122.205) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.122.205: icmp_seq=1 ttl=254 time=4.03 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.122.205: icmp_seq=2 ttl=254 time=10.2 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.122.205: icmp_seq=3 ttl=254 time=7.50 ms
^C
--- 192.168.122.205 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2004ms

distro@ubuntu:/home$ sudo netstat -telnup | grep syslog
udp        0      0 192.168.145.140:514     0.0.0.0:*                           0          98403       5570/syslog-ng

## Router is configured fine-

logging buffered 4096
logging trap debugging
logging facility syslog
logging source-interface FastEthernet0/0
logging 192.168.145.140
 logging synchronous
 logging synchronous
 logging synchronous level all
ntp logging

Router1#show log
 Trap logging: level debugging, 404 message lines logged
        Logging to 192.168.145.140  (udp port 514,  audit disabled,
              authentication disabled, encryption disabled, link up),
              164 message lines logged,

But the issue I am not able to see any logs.Nor there are any files created - 
/var/log/dev.log

Also there is another issue were when I wanted to test the syslog connectivity

distro@ubuntu:/home$ telnet 192.168.145.140 514
Trying 192.168.145.140...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

As you can imagine the connectivity fails from Router telnetting into the syslog server.

There is no firewall configuration -

distro@ubuntu:/home$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Kindly advice.

Comment: Hi,
Try removing the filter from the log path and see if messages start arriving. 
Also, you can try to start syslog-ng with the -Fevd command-line options to see if it reports a specific error. Cisco devices tend to send messages that are not syslog compliant, so you might have some parsing errors. If that's the case, let me know.